# Save vars back in a file automatically after including and modifying it

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Is there anything like `save_vars` in Ansible that would automatically save modified var/fact imported with `include_vars`?

The following code serves the purpose but it is not an elegant solution.

```
# vars/my_vars.json
{
    "my_password": "Velicanstveni", 
    "my_username": "Franjo"
}


# playbook.yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: fetch vars
      include_vars:
        file: my_vars.json
        name: playbook_var

    - name: change var
      set_fact:
        playbook_var: "{{ playbook_var|combine({'my_username': 'Njofra' }) }}"

    - name: save var to file
      copy:
        content: "{{ playbook_var | to_nice_json }}"
        dest: vars/my_vars.json
```

I was wondering if there is an option in Ansible we can turn on so that whenever the var/fact is changed, during the playbook execution, this is automatically updated in the file var was imported from. The background problem I am trying to solve is having global variables in Ansible. The idea is to save global vars in a file. Ansible has system of hostavars which is collection of per-hostname variables but not all data is always host-related.

Comment: Why would you save facts? The idea behind Ansible is that ansible *is* your configuration and it's Ansible the sets your hosts. What's on the host itself is less relevant.

Comment: @ColOfAbRiX In my scenario I have three network devices in the cluster. I check the cluster state and based on that I set the flag. That flag is used in subsequent plays and tasks. The playbook has many plays. During the playbook run cluster state may change several times and therefore its state is checked more than once and flag can be reset to different value. That flag is really cluster related rather than host related and it would make sense to save it in a global var.

Comment: Is it becuse you can't set the network device completely with Ansible and you need to read their status? When I have a setting that I need to apply to a cluster I use group variables.
If you can set all the things you need on the network devices without knowing their state beforehand, I recommend you that. If not it's a more tricky business. Have a look at this if it helps a bit: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#caching-facts

Answer (score 0):

I think a [fact cache](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/plugins/cache.html) will plus or minus do that, although it may have some sharp edges to getting it right, since that's not exactly the problem it is trying to solve. The [json cache plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/plugins/cache/jsonfile.html) sounds like it is most likely what you want, but there is a [yaml cache plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/plugins/cache/yaml.html), too.

The bad news is that, as far as I can tell, one cannot configure those caching URIs via the playbook, rather one must use either the environment variable or an `ansible.cfg` setting.